# Drupal site crashes when clearing the cache after Entity API installation

Tags: entities

I'm trying to install the module [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity). But if I clear the cache after the installation, my Drupal site crashes (i.e. something is causing a signal segmentation fault). I can't figure out why, because I have used the Entity API module before without any problems.

I'm using Drupal 7.13. I have tried both available versions, but it doesn't work. I have manually installed the module.

Can anyone please help me to understand what's going on?

Comment: did you check the apache error log ? can you post info from there ?

Comment: No-one is going to be able to help without any more information.  Is it a fresh install of Drupal? Define "crash", is there an error message in any of your logs?

Comment: try using this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7

Comment: did you enable entity_token, too ? how many node / entity types / fields do you have ?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how I can find more information. I'm quite now at Drupal, so I don't know where I can find errors logs from Drupal and other things that I need. No I didn't enable entity_token. 

I need the Entity API for the Field collection module. I don't know how many nodes I have. I'm not using a fresh installation of Drupal. Can anyone help me how I can investigate the problem?

Comment: I have found a solution. The problem was that I had an old version of the module i18n. You can read about the solution here:
http://drupal.org/node/1542390